# Problem On Getting Data From Arduino It outputs end line chracters Python

Tags: python, arduino

Greetings how can I remove \r\n and "['']" line?
It is a barometric data logger. My future plans are making a gui and showing the values there.
And my pcb has a bluetooth to how can I add bluetooth support.

Python Code

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', baudrate = 9600, timeout=1)
 while 1:
  arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
  parsed = arduinoData.split(',')
  print(parsed)
```

Python Output

```
enter code here
['']
['26.03', '882.70', '1340.80\r\n']
['']
['26.03', '882.68', '1341.02\r\n']
['']
['26.03', '882.66', '1341.13\r\n']
['']
['26.03', '882.66', '1341.14\r\n']
```

Arduino Code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>

Adafruit_BMP280 bme;
#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1037.3)



 void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
   bme.begin(0x76);
  }

 void loop() {
  Serial.print(bme.readTemperature());
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(bme.readPressure()/100);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA));
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
```

}

Comment: `.strip()` can remove the `\r\n`, and something like `if not arduinoData: continue` can help you avoid the empty results.

Comment: Ask one question per question. Your additional question about Bluetooth is totally unrelated to the problem you describe here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
parsed = arduinoData.split(',')
```

with

```
parsed = [datum.strip() for datum in arduinoData.split(',')]
```

which will strip whitespace from both sides of each item. `\r` and `\n` count as whitespace, so it'll remove that.

---

Additionally, it looks like

```
Serial.print(bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA));
```

already outputs a newline - the empty lists you're getting might be from the *second* newline you get from `Serial.println("")`. Try removing that line and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks it solved the \r\n issue but how can i get rid of the ['']

Comment: @RüzgarErik I updated my answer with a suggestion for that.

Comment: '['25.65', '882.71', '1340.7525.65', '882.71', '1340.68']
['25.65', '882.69', '1340.92']
['25.65', '882.69', '1340.9025.64', '882.69', '1340.88']'

Comment: Now i got this output

Comment: That's what you're looking for, right? Or did you want them as numbers instead of strings? In that case, maybe do `float(datum.strip())`.